# Error while accessing style property "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change font color of any html element using javascript but console is showing this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null". Similar issue happens while accessing other style poperties.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="heading">Login</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the javascript I am using

```
(function(){
    window.onload=function(){
        var el=document.getElementById("h1");
        el.style.color= "green";
    };
}());
```

Comment: Change id `var el=document.getElementById("heading");`

Answer (score 1):

You have there no `#h1` element. The correct `id` value in this case is `heading`.

```
var el=document.getElementById("heading");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `getElementById` and passing `h1` to it, which is incorrect. The id of the heading is `heading`.

Change to:

```
var el=document.getElementById("heading");
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to change "h1" to "heading"

```
(function(){
    window.onload=function(){
        var el=document.getElementById("heading");
        el.style.color= "green";
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

h1 is not Id its a tag
`var el=document.getElementById("h1");`

so if you want to change all  elements you need to use getElementsByTagName
like this

```
var el=document. getElementsByTagName("h1");
to change a certain element like in your case "<h1 id="heading">Login</h1>"
use var `el=document.getElementById("heading");`
```